# Очистка массива php

Tags: php, массивы

Здравствуйте. Существует примерно такой массив:

```
$abc = array(
    0 => array('user_id' => '2'),
    10 => array('user_id' => '2', 'useru_id' => '4'),
    11 => array('user_id' => '2', 'useru_id' => '3'),
    14 => array('user_id' => '4', 'useru_id' => '2'),
    16 => array('user_id' => '4', 'useru_id' => '3'),
);
```

Нужно его преобразовать с условием, что user_id = 2 и useru_id = 4 или user_id = 4 и useru_id = 2 что бы получилось так:

```
Array
(
    [10] => {Любой текст}
    [14] => {Любой текст}
)
```

Код должен выполняться как можно быстрее, т.к. изначальный массив может быть ОЧЕНЬ БОЛЬШИМ.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$abc = array(
    0 => array('user_id' => '2'),
    10 => array('user_id' => '2', 'useru_id' => '4'),
    11 => array('user_id' => '2', 'useru_id' => '3'),
    14 => array('user_id' => '4', 'useru_id' => '2'),
    16 => array('user_id' => '4', 'useru_id' => '3'),
);

$cba = [];
foreach($abc as $key => $item){
    // Проверка существования обоих ключей, а так же чтобы один из них был 2, второй - 4 (порядок неважен)
    if((isset($item['user_id']) && isset($item['useru_id'])) && (($item['user_id'] == 4 || $item['user_id'] == 2) && ($item['useru_id'] == 4 || $item['useru_id'] == 2)))
        $cba[$key] = $item; // Добавляется сам массив, но можно добавить {Любой текст}
}
var_dump($cba);
```

https://repl.it/Ck4G/0

---

Быстрее уже не выйдет, нативные конструкции.

Comment: если иссеты выкинуть, что рабоатть не будет?

Comment: Вообще-то тут лучше функцию аррай мэп заюзать... И мож хватит набивать рейтинг отвечая на заведомо вопрос для фриланса а не для стэковерфлоу.

Comment: @Jean-Claude, будет в принципе...

Comment: @Naumov, что быстрее - вопрос, требующий тестов. Кажется мне что `array_map` дороже цикла выйдет. Хотя не знаю точно. И для фриланса как-то мелкое задание, Вы погорячились, вероятно.

Comment: @Naumov тебе чи не пофиг на рейтинг человека, предложи свой ответ